# class path resource [../EnableTransactionManagement.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring

i'm having this error in my MVC spring project made in the spring tool suite.
Obviously the java file is there and there is no compilation error in there, also i have included the respective jars. the stand-alone program for test runs fine, but when i try to publish on the test server, the web page display the HTTP 500 status error.

I made another default web project with spring, and it works,the server display the home page, i used this template to make my own project, and since i didn't touched configuration files unrelated to the webserver (only spring and hibernate xml files) i'm not sure why i'm getting this.

Here is the full message from the  stack trace(only the error)

> HTTP 500 status - Servlet.init () for servlet threw exception appServlet
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: mvc.test.hib.hibernateConfig;
>
> nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

here is the mentioned java file where is supposed to be the error

```
package mvc.test.hib;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"mvc.test.hib" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class hibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "mvc.test.hib" });
       sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
       return sessionFactory;
    }
    
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
       dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
       dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
       dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
       return dataSource;
   }
    
   private Properties hibernateProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
       properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
       properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
       return properties;        
   }
    
   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
      return txManager;
   }
}
```

EDIT: i thougth i could the error because i didn´t have added the Jar, i downloaded the jar that contains the **org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.class**, still the same message. i'm lost.

I'm not using maven, all jars are imported manually

Comment: How are you deploying to your servlet container? Are the jar deployed correctly?

Comment: @RC. I'm using the Spring Tool Suite default server VMware VFabric for test, i'm quite new to deploying, reading a bit i have seen the folder where is deployed the project, i don't see any war or ear files. but all the jars are in the lib folder